# Aligning table columns PHP

Tags: php, html

I have this table that for some reason, isn't aligning properly like I want it to. I have 3 columns, 1 row. But for some strange reason, when I have the stuff entered, it's not aligning like it's suppose to.

```
<?php

        $grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topsongs ORDER BY number limit 10 ");    

            if (mysql_num_rows($grab)==0) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-note-x'>Sorry, it looks like their are no Top Songs Listed</div>";
    }

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($grab)){

      ?>

<table style="border-spacing: 10px;width:100%;clear:both;overflow:hidden;border: 1px #EBEBEB solid;border-bottom: 2px #EBEBEB solid;padding:5px;margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:10px;" class="border-radius">
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo stripslashes($row['number']); ?></td>
        <td><img class="border-radius" width="70" height="70" src="<?php echo stripslashes($row['dpic']); ?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo stripslashes($row['songname']); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

         <?php } ?>
```

you guys happen to know what it is, that I'm doing wrong? image here: http://screencloud.net/v/oN4l

Comment: place this <td align="center"> in td

Comment: how it suppose to align ?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: it should align 1 by 1 by 1. The image matches up with the images, the  "songname" is suppose to align with the other songnames. it's all messy, haha

Answer (score 2):

You create separate tables for each row. Thus for each row, the column widths are calculated without taking the other rows (which are in other tables) into account.

Move `<table>` to before the loop and `</table>` to after the loop, so that you have only one table that holds all the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer you want it

```
<?php

        $grab = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM topsongs ORDER BY number limit 10 ");    

            if (mysql_num_rows($grab)==0) {
        echo "<div class='alert alert-note-x'>Sorry, it looks like their are no Top Songs Listed</div>";
    } 
?>

<table style="border-spacing: 10px;width:100%;clear:both;overflow:hidden;border: 1px #EBEBEB solid;border-bottom: 2px #EBEBEB solid;padding:5px;margin-top:3px;margin-bottom:10px;" class="border-radius">
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($grab)){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo stripslashes($row['number']); ?></td>
        <td><img class="border-radius" width="70" height="70" src="<?php echo stripslashes($row['dpic']); ?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo stripslashes($row['songname']); ?></td>
    </tr>
         <?php } ?> 
</table>
```

Replace your code and try this

Answer (score -1):

Use align attribute in `<td>` like `<td align="left">`